# Can I use a dblink connecting DB2 and Oracle be used for DML operations on DB2?

Tags: oracle, db2, oracle12c, data-migration, dblink

I have a database link that connects a DB2 database and an ORACLE database. My prime intention is to migrate data from the source (DB2) to the target (ORACLE). Now, after the migration, the discrepant records on my target needs to be sent back to the source for further actions. Can this be done using the same DBLINK??

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that, unless you want to insert, update, delete data in an readonly object. But take care at the types differences between tve two (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/doc.40/e18460/oracle_db2_compared.htm#RPTID114).

Answer (score 0):

You could also federate Db2 to Oracle and pull the data back again...

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/tlsorc01.html